# Nested selector with concatenation and multiple classes

Tags: sass

I want to use nested classes with concatenation to use selection with multiples classes. I have a syntax problem.

To be clear, I want :

```
.control {
    width: 10em;

    &.&--small { // <-- Not working : Syntax error
      width: 5em;
    }
}
```

To be outputted to :

```
.control {
    width: 10em;
}

.control.control--small {
    width: 5em;
}
```

Possible ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way. try `&.control--small`

Comment: Note that what you've written would (theoretically) compile to `.control..control--small` (note the double periods).

Comment: Yes, @yarons but I would know if I can use the &

Comment: Ok, it works, I used the `#{&}` syntax : http://sassmeister.com/gist/c21fde99c9f4c145174a